# Other - Project does not show technologies in the CV

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, developer-story

I have a [CV](https://stackoverflow.com/cv/xameeramir) and a [story](https://stackoverflow.com/story/xameeramir), the story shows the technologies listed for example under the **SBH chatbot service**:

[image: Tech listed under story]

I expected the same experience for the CV as well

[image: No tech listed under CV]

I just request to make CV also list the technologies used for each feature.

Can someone please take this either as bug/ feature request, whatever?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies for the late response. We haven't had a team working on the developer story feature for a while.

This was indeed a bug, and the fix will be going out shortly with our next production build.

Thanks so much for your report!

Comment: when is your next release?

Comment: @student we build a couple times a day, so you should be able to see the tags on your project now